# Resolving "SSLProxyEngine" issue on CentOS CWP

Tags: reverse-proxy, centos8, cwp

I want to enable "SSLProxyEngine", for one of my websites, in the CWP log viewer I am getting the below error, please guide how to resolve the same:

I am using CentOS CWP

---

### [Sat May 29 18:58:00.673315 2021] [ssl:error] [pid 1653653:tid 139774762817280] [remote IP:443] AH01961: SSL Proxy requested for domain:80 but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]
[Sat May 29 18:58:00.673378 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 1653653:tid 139774762817280] AH00961: HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for IP:443 ([www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com))

I am trying to make this URL work "https://example.com/jewellery-showroom-interior" which is working fine when SSL is not enabled, however, generating 500 error in case SSL is being used

Answer (score 1):

As error dictate you have added not SSL certificate for your domain. I recommend you use AUTOSSL in cwp to do this its hustle free unless you want to manually install then you will need to create CSR and private key first, once the certificate is issued to you  go to **Webservers settings > SSL Certificate > Manual Install**.

Also error dictates you need to set Apache ProxyPass (SSLProxyEngine) in vHosts config under WebServers_domain option in cwp sidebar OR add one/edit your domain vHost  here /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/conf/web_servers/.

Add: `SSLEngine On` and `SSLProxyEngine on` before any proxypass call like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apachekeys/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apachekeys/example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apachekeys/some.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apachekeys/ca.pem
    ProxyHTMLInterp On
    ProxyHTMLExtended On   
    ProxyPass / https://server_ip/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://server_ip/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
    
    
    ProxyPass / https://example.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://example.com:8080/
```